# Deleting WebGL contexts after testing for WebGL context

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl

Out of curiosity I've wanted to see what context of WebGL is supported by various visitors using the following code:

```
var e = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = ['webgl','ms-webgl','experimental-webgl','moz-webgl']; 
for (var y = -1, len = c.length; ++y < len;)
{
 try {if (e.getContext(c[y])) {/*do-a-jig*/ break;}} catch(e) {}
}
```

Unfortunately this created a very difficult to reproduce bug reported in the web developer console:

> WebGL warning: Exceeded 16 live WebGL contexts for this principal,
>   losing the least recently used one.

So the question is simply put, after testing for a context how do I delete that context to avoid spawning this error?

Comment: Whats wrong with `for (var y=0; y<c.length; y++)` .

Comment: `moz-webgl` and `ms-webgl` do not exist

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like:   *(untested)*

```
var e = document.createElement('canvas');
var c = ['webgl','ms-webgl','experimental-webgl','moz-webgl']; 

var found = '';
for (var y=0; y<c.length; y++)
{
    try {
        var ctx = e.getContext(c[y]);
        if (ctx) {
            found = c[y];
            ctx.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();
            break;
        }

    } catch(e) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot delete it. You should create only 1 time and cache it for reuse.